# Can the TinyWeb Framework run handlers with session state off?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-state, tinyweb

I am developing a simple website with the TinyWeb framework and Spark view engine.

Environment is Visual Studio 2011 developer preview & .net 4.5

Everything works well until I turn off session state.

When I turn session state off previously working urls return 404's
I think iis is not running the TinyWeb handler code. Since it says it was the static file handler?

Is there a way to get TinyWeb to handle requests with out having to have session state on?

Here is the error details.

Module:    IIS Web Core

Notification:    MapRequestHandler

**Handler:**    StaticFile

Error Code:    0x80070002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer looks like no. Requests are processed by a HttpHandler class and it implements the IRequiresSessionState.